How can i select all the elements surrounding a specific element just like the has() selector but in all directions
This is my HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Hovering Boxes</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script>
        let container = document.getElementById('container');
        let boxCount = 100;

        for(let i = 0; i < boxCount; i++) {
            let box = document.createElement('div');
            box.className = 'box';
            container.appendChild(box);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>

And this is my CSS:
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
}

#container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    perspective: 1000px;
}

.box {
    background-color: red;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: transform 0.5s, filter 0.3s;
}

.box:hover {
    transform: translateZ(150px);
    filter: brightness(1);
    background-color: #87F1FF;
}

.box:hover + * {
    transform: translateZ(100px) rotateY(60deg);
    filter: brightness(0.8);
}

.box:hover + * + * {
    transform: translateZ(50px) rotateY(30deg);
    filter: brightness(0.6);
}



.box:hover + * + * + * {
    transform: translateZ(25px) rotateY(15deg);
    filter: brightness(0.4);
}

.box:has(+ *:hover) {
    transform: translateZ(100px) rotateY(-60deg);
    filter: brightness(0.8);
}

.box:has(+ * + *:hover) {
    transform: translateZ(50px) rotateY(-30deg);
    filter: brightness(0.6);
}

.box:has(+ * + * + *:hover) {
    transform: translateZ(25px) rotateY(-15deg);
    filter: brightness(0.4);
}

This code currently selects the hovered element and sets effects to its following and preceding elements. However, I also want the top and bottom elements relative to the hovered element to receive similar effects.
What would be the best approach to select and style these top and bottom elements when hovering over a box?
I have tried using JavaScript to achieve this but couldn't find an effective solution. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

What layout of your boxes are you anticipating. 1010, 205 etc?

the layout can be any size.  The boxes are setup in grid like structure and my current code is giving effects to the preceding and following of the box being hovered.

In grid like structure i want to find a way to select all the surrounding elements of the hovered element.

Unless the size of the grid is known CSS cannot do this, it can't detect what row an an element is on. You need Javascript.

i am not using a grid and the elements is position by flexbox. when the boxes are positioned they formed a grid(not the grid of css) like structure. i get your point i will try.

You called it a "grid like structure" so that is the term I used.

sorry for the confusion.



* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
}

#container {
    display: grid;
    justify-content: center;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 0fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(10, 0fr);
    width: 90%;
    perspective: 1000px;
}

.hovered-top {
    background-color: chartreuse;
}

.box {
    background-color: red;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: transform 0.2s, filter 0.2s;
}

.box:hover {
    transform: translateZ(150px);
    filter: brightness(1);
    background-color: #87F1FF;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>hovering boxes</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script>
                const container = document.getElementById('container');
                    const rows = 10;
                    const cols = 10;
                    const boxCount = rows * cols;

                    for (let i = 0; i < boxCount; i++) {
                        const box = document.createElement('div');
                        box.classList.add('box');
                        container.appendChild(box);
                    }

                    const boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box');

                    boxes.forEach((box, index) => {
                        box.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
                            const row = Math.floor(index / cols);
                            const col = index % cols;

                            boxes.forEach((b, i) => {
                                const bRow = Math.floor(i / cols);
                                const bCol = i % cols;
                                const distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(row - bRow, 2) + Math.pow(col - bCol, 2));
                                b.style.transform = `translateZ(${100 - distance * 10}px)`;
                                b.style.filter = `brightness(${1 - distance * 0.1})`;
                                b.style.transitionDelay = `${distance * 50}ms`;
                            });
                        });

                        box.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
                            boxes.forEach(b => {
                                b.style.transform = 'translateZ(0)';
                                b.style.filter = 'brightness(0)';
                                b.style.transitionDelay = '0ms';
                            });
                        });
                    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>




As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
